# For loop only stores one value into a vector instead of multiple

Tags: r

Im trying to store all the prime numbers in a vector into an object.

```
Q8.16 <-function(vector){
 
  for(i in 1:length(vector)){
    
     if (vector[i] == 2L || all(vector[i] %% 2L:ceiling(sqrt(vector[i])) != 0)){
       prime1<-NULL
       prime1<-append(prime1,vector[i])
        
     
     }
  }
 prime1
  }
  

sample1<-sample(1:1000 ,1000)
Q8.16(sample1)
```

The output I get from it is only one digit instead of a vector with all the prime numbers. Why is this happening?

Comment: `emptyvector` is never used, and `return` exits the function immediately when it finds the first prime number.

Comment: Would you please explain what is the purpose of this loop? So maybe I can rewrite it.

Comment: @pseudospin i removed those and i still only get one value

Comment: @AnoushiravanR The loop basically has to look for prime numbers in a  vector with whole positive numbers. It then has to return all of those prime numbers. Is that clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your intention correctly, it looks like the only change you need to make is move `prime1<-NULL` just before the for-loop. In your version of the code, you were resetting the list of primes every time you found a new one. The fixed version (with spacing tidied up) is below.

```r
Q8.16 <- function(vector) {
  prime1 <- NULL  # moved this outside the for-loop
  for (i in 1:length(vector)) {
    if (vector[i] == 2L || all(vector[i] %% 2L:ceiling(sqrt(vector[i])) != 0)) {
      prime1 <- append(prime1, vector[i])
    }
  }
  prime1
}

sample1 <- sample(1:1000, 1000)
Q8.16(sample1)
```

Testing it with `sample1 <- 1:100` returns `[1]  2  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97` which looks correct to me.

Comment: oh my i was so blind. Thank you for bringing that to my attention.